# How can i add a html tag "sup" and "sub" in a text shape when i use Konva.Text?

Tags: konvajs

KonvaJS is a excellent canvas plugin,it's easy to use ,a lot of demos,and detailed api document.

But i have a problem about Konva.Text, When I want to display fraction number like "<sup>7</sup>/<sub>8</sub>",it's show as a plain text <sup>7</sup>/<sub>8</sub> , how can i do?

As far as I know fabric has analogous method called setSuperscript and setSubscript, can our Konva.Text be achieved?

Comment: Konvajs docs for the text object do not provide for superscript and subscript. See https://konvajs.org/api/Konva.Text.html

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to draw it manually with three shapes:

```
function createFraction(sup, sub) {
  const group = new Konva.Group();
  group.add(new Konva.Text({
    align: 'right',
    width: 100,
    x: -100,
    text: sup
  }));
  group.add(new Konva.Text({
    text: sub,
    y: 13,
    x: 2
  }));
  group.add(new Konva.Line({
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 1,
    points: [5, 4, -5, 20],
    text: sub,
  }));
  return group;
}


const fraction = createFraction('7', '8');
fraction.position({ x: 50, y: 50});

layer.add(fraction);
```

https://jsbin.com/vahavimowa/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thank you for your advice! But I found it difficult to join other text in Konva. Label!

If it could be part of Konva. Label, it would be perfect.